# Used e2fsck on my Synology NAS and lost all my data .. possible to recover?

Tags: synology, e2fsck

I had some file system issues after a power loss that I wasn't able to fix using anything suggested in DSM.

Anyway, I stupidly followed advise found online to run **e2fsck** in terminal to check and repair file errors. After it completed my NAS reports 0% used of my 10TB volume ( it was 50% before).

I'm gutted and annoyed as I had a lot of personal & sentimental files on it, have I lost all my files ? Is there anyway to undo/recover now ? TIA

Comment: fsck is dangerous. Especially if it starts asking questions. There is no undo unless you went out of your way to specify it and made no other modifications. You can try your luck with photorec... with a new disk as recovery location. Otherwise try to recover the files from any other media that ever had a copy of them...